# ASP.NET Core and Identity Server Authentication for SPA

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, single-page-application

I am starting a project with ASP.NET Core as an API Server and Angular 6 for the Frontend part but i am a bit lost with which exactly is the right way to authenticate users with the Identity Framework.

I read the documentation on http://docs.identityserver.io and also checked also the samples on github https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

Which is the correct way to authenticate users for my project ? I think i need the section "Using ASP.NET Core Identity" or "Adding User Authentication using OpenID Connect or "Adding Javascript Client" but i am not sure.

Which one best suits me?